# Expresión regular para validad alfanumérico y con longitud menor o igual a 16

Tags: javascript

Necesito validar que un textbox en js permita solo ingresar 16 o menos caracteres alfanuméricos:

Estaba tratando de usar algo así: ^([0-9]){16}$ pero no me funciona. Alguie que me pueda orientar por favor. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar con esta regla:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,16}$/
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("probar");
var input = document.getElementById("prueba");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  var regxp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,16}$/;
  alert(regxp.test(input.value));

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="prueba"><button id="probar">Probar</button>
```

Comment: era lo que necesitaba, funciono perfecto, muchas gracias!